# OpenCV solvePnP barreldistoriton

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, distortion

I'm using OpenCVs solvePnP to get the pose/positon of the camera.
I'm doing this by using points selected by the user, on an image that is already calibrated and have applied the fix for radial and tangential distortion.

However, it seems solvePnP() takes distortion coefficients as input in addition to the points selected in the image, which I suppose means taht SolvePnP applies the distortion-fix on the points given as input to the function.

This would create a minor error in my program, since the source image is already barrel-distorted, right?

If so, how can I make solvePnP() ignore the barreldistortion? Can I pass a vector with distortion-coefficients set to just 1's? Or should i set all values to 0?
Some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past I have just passed an empty cv::Mat

```
cv::solvePnP(world_points, image_points, camera_mat, cv::Mat(), rotation_vector, translation_vector);
```

the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#cv-solvepnp) says that if you pass NULL it will set all the coefficients to 0 for you.

Comment: Ahh, of course. I should've read the documentation a bit better.
Thanks.

Another question: Regarding the camera_mat, if I am using an image which is ALREADY corrected by initUndistortMap() + remap(), what kind of camera matrix is the most correct to give as input to the solvepnp? The camera matrix from the correction, or a simple Mat::eye() ?

Comment: Replacing `cv::Mat()` with `cv::noArray()` has the same effect but makes the intent a little bit clearer.

Comment: @HenrikKjusAlstad a camera matrix (call it C) mapps 3d world coordinates to 2d image coordinates.  solvePnP essentially returns a transform (call it T) such that C*T*world_coordinate = image_coordinate to the best of its ability.  Your camera matrix is defined by your camera intrinsic parameters